# Using sqlite3 with sequelize to build a desktop app using electron. Only few tables are getting created during production

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, sequelize.js, electron-builder

everyone. I have encountered a very strange bug. I am using sqlite3 to create a desktop app along with sequelize as an ORM. I tried to build my app today for the first time and installed the setup which was created. The app only created a few of the tables that I had programmed. The app is supposed to create the following tables.

[image]

But when running in production mode. Then it creates only the following tables.

[image]

The table "items" and all the tables involving itemId as a foreign key are missing. I am not sure which part of the code will be relevant to share, so I am sharing the link to the Git where I am updating the project.
https://github.com/Srajan1/my-shop-app.

I have also checked the sequelize logs in the debugging mode and they seem to be working fine and creating all the tables.
[image]

Comment: I did a clone of your repository with a fresh DB Sequelize worked as expected, all tables and relationships were created

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. I found out that there was some error in the Items model declaration. Which I have fixed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had not defined the Item model the right way. This is what I should have done.

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../database/db");
const Metric = require("./metricModel");

const Item = sequelize.define(
  "Item",
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    hsn: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    available: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    incoming: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    tableName: "items",
    freezeTableName: true,
  }
);

Item.belongsTo(Metric, { foreignKey: "metricId", targetKey: "id" });
module.exports = Item;
```